# Parameterless Constructor error

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, interface, global-asax

Hi I am initializing interface in the Global.ascx like this

```
private static SimpleMembershipInitializer _initializer;
private static object _initializerLock = new object();
private static bool _isInitialized;



public SimpleMembershipInitializer(IAccountHelper iAccountHelper)
{              
   _accountHelper = iAccountHelper;
   _accountHelper.SimpleMembershipInitializer();

}


#endregion
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    SimpleInjector.SetupDependencyInjection();
    // Ensure ASP.NET Simple Membership is initialized only once per app start
    LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
}
```

But i am getting an error

> The lazily-initialized type does not have a public, parameterless constructor.

What i am doing wrong here?

Alternatively if I change the code with the following

```
public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
{                  
   _accountHelper = new AccountHelper();                 
   _accountHelper.SimpleMembershipInitializer();                                       
}
```

The code works fine.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the code which is giving the error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized` need that your class have public parameterless constructor. If your class constructor has parameter, then the initializer doesn't know how to get or instantiate those parameters.

I recommend you to use a dependency injection library to initialize your dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Which library should i use and is there any implementation example from Global.asax. Thanks

Comment: @OwaisAhmed [SimpleInjector](https://simpleinjector.org/index.html) or [Autofac](https://autofac.org/). They have a lot of features and well documented. Complete with a lot of example for various scenario.

Comment: If you see my code i am using SimpleInjector  which is registering IAccountHelper but how can i call the SimpleMembershipInitializer() method which is inside IAccountHelper in Global.asax

Comment: Then just register `SimpleMembershipInitializer` into the container, and provide initialization logic there. Then use `SimpleMembershipInitializer` as your controller constructor parameter. It should initialized automatically.